# Bootstrap Modal page.html is not working with ng-include

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am calling a Bootstrap Model on hyperlink. 
My code was in "MasterPageNavBar.html"

```
 <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Login/SignUp</a>
```

Here is my completed code "MasterPageNavBar.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/Collapse.JS"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>AngularJS Tutorial</h3> 
            <nav class="navbar  navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#mynavbar" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a data-ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a data-ui-sref="contactus">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Login/SignUp</a>

                                <!-- Modal HTML -->
                            <form>
                                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body form-group">
                                                <input style="margin-bottom:15px" type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="User Name ---" />
                                                <input style="margin-bottom:5px" type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Password" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Login</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                 </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run alone this page , Modal was working fine. Here is the output of a model.
[image]

up to here code is fine.

***My Problem is here***

I am calling this "MasterPageNavBar.html page in another page "index.html". Here is my "Index.html" code( this my start page).

```
**<div ng-include="'../Views/MasterPageNavBar.html'"></div>**

<div ng-include="'../Views/ContentPage.html'"></div>
```

***Modal window is not working through running "Index.html" page.***

[image]

One thing i have noticed that " when on click Login link 'UI-Route functionality is working' and it's is looking for a myModel page and its is not finding. Below is my ui.route module. ( I don't want to call this ui.rotuer on click Login link.

```
 **<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Login/SignUp</a>**
```

[image]

```
  var myrouting=angular.module('routingDemoApp', ['ui.router'])
    myrouting.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // For any unmatched url, send to /business
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("", "/index")

        $stateProvider
                .state('index', {
                    url: "/index",
                    templateUrl: "../Views/home.html"
                })
                .state('contactus', {
                    url: "/contactus",
                    templateUrl: "../Views/contactus.html",

                })

                 .state('home', {
                     url: "/home",
                     templateUrl: "../Views/home.html",
                 })
```

Comment: May be your browser cache is not getting cleared, this happens a lot of times with me. try Hitting CTRL+F5 

And also check if the specified resources are available in the specified folder for ng-include tags

Comment: if your so sure that your going to use that modal only from the Home page may be you can include that in the same page or you can pass the HTML as a template in .state

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click to open your modal as given below:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="openModal()" data-toggle="modal">Login/SignUp</a>
```

In your controller write the following code:

```
$scope.openModal= function(){ $("#myModal").modal("show"); }
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Hi, when i run alone MasterpageNavBar.html Modal is working fine.          <a href="" class="classes"  data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Login/SignUp</a>                                                                     . when i run  this by using ng-inlcude in index.html  'modal' is not working.                                                                                             <body ng-app="theapp">
    <div ng-include="'../Views/MasterPageNavBar.html'"></div>                 
    <div ng-include="'../Views/ContentPage.html'"></div>
  
</body>

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the `data-target` attribute that Bootstrap supports (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes).  Use it like `data-target="#myModal"` and remove the `href=""`.  Then Angular will not attempt to navigate to it.

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'modal' at $scope.openModal (http://localhost:56200/Scripts/main.js:32:9)

Comment: I'm going to run with the assumption that you got your responses flip flopped between myself and Shailendra's response.  If you did, can you pop open the devTools and see what the DOM has?  Is it actually getting the contents of the `MasterPageNavBar` view loaded from the `ng-include`?

Comment: Hi  Dave, I can see model created from ng-include.